# R xts time series compare to previous observation

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I've imported some intraday financial time series data (OHLC) into an xts object.
I now want to analyse how often the gap between the previous days close and next days open was filled during this day (and further down what influences the size of the gap, day of week etc. had on the stats).

I've resampled the data via `to.daily()` into a daily series, but how can I now filter for days where

```
day[i-1]$Close >= day[i]$Low & day[i-1]$Close <= day[i]$High
```

and ideally add `day[i-1]$Close` as an additional column for reference to the resulting subset?

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible `xts` object and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution via

```
merge(d1, lag(d1$Close))
```

Now you have the previous days close as an additional column and can now filter as usual within one row.